# How can I use Tess4j with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tesseract, tess4j

I would like to do OCR with java and I use IntelliJ. But I don't know what are the files I need for my project.

My code is just a simple OCR:

```
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;

import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        File f = new File("asd.jpg");

        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(f);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coming from Visual Studio / F#, now using IntelliJ / SBT / Scala, I am trying to wrap my head around how to add tess4j... Just here to give mental support: you are not alone. I will write an answer if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency on `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```